# Why do none of my h tags show up on browsers

Tags: html, header

Question, why do none of my h tags (h1, h2, h3) show up on some browsers ie: internet explorer. they show up in Google chrome, firefox and safari fine???
http://mcj.site40.net

Comment: show up fine in FF here.

Comment: Probably something to do with the cufon text replacement you're using...

Answer (score 2):

You headings are missing because you are using **[Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)** which requires canvas and has no fallback mechanisms for browsers which do not support it or have issues with it (IE etc.)

**EDIT:** Use `@font-face` combined with fonts from, lets say, **[FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)** and you will be on the safe side of using custom fonts on the web for most modern browsers. It even has a **[@font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)** if you want to use your own fonts. But do make sure that you are legally allowed to use the fonts if you want to use the generator with your own fonts.

Comment: Thanks, so if i just remove Cufon it should work?!?

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer.